# How to remove by default mandatory fields in Bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

[Screen-shots of fields to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAeq4.png)

Fields to be removed are following
1. Version [of product]
2. Hardware
3. OS

Answer (score 0):

You need to change on:

Path -> bugzilla\template\en\default\bug\create

File -> create.html.tmpl

First I deleted Perl code and left just the HTML as below and it workded:

```
<input type="hidden" name="version" size="6" maxlength="6" value="unspecified">
<input type="hidden" name="rep_platform" size="6" maxlength="6" value="PC">
<input type="hidden" name="op_sys" size="6" maxlength="6" value="Windows XP">
```